# What can I do about this error after attempting to install CiviCRM on a Wordpress site: Table 'myprefix_civicrm.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist

Tags: wordpress, error, installation

My attempt to install CiviCRM on a WordPress site (in a separate database) failed after creating only one table in the database. I didn't record the error, thinking I could just delete the database and the files from the Plugins folder, then run things again. After recreating an empty INNODB database and re-extracting the files into the plugins directory, when I go to Plugins.php and click Activate, I get the following error:

Initialization Error

```
Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => simpleHandler
        )

    [code] => -18
    [message] => DB Error: no such table
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)
 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'myprefix_civicrm.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)
     [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'myprefix_civicrm.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such table" code=-18 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::simpleHandler prefix="" info="SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)
 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'myprefix_civicrm.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]"]
)
```

The only way to get rid of it is to rename the Plugins folder Plugins.Hold, then revisit the plugins page. However, as soon as I rename the folder back and click Activate again, I get the same error.

I don't have any caching plugins on the site.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the civicrm folder in the wp-content/uploads folder was preventing a clean reinstall. Deleting that folder allowed me to start the install over.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Table 'your-schema.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist
 Table 'civicrm_setting' doesn't exist
```

If you're getting such error, check that your database import was successful  and that all the tables were imported ok.  Login to your db server and change to your db then do "show tables".