# Installation failure - doesn't to write to database (D7)

Tags: drupal, installation, install

I'm unable to install CiviCRM under Drupal 7.  This is something I've done dozens of times, to be clear.  I install a clean D7 system (7.97 but also tried 7.95), the Civi install runs, I then get the usual screen that invites me to configure the install, but clicking that link fails because the database hasn't been written to.  I raised a ticket with the hosting company as I surmised that something their end had changed - they tried and failed to install in the same way too, but came back to say it was an application problem. For the nth time I now have a clean D7 system sitting there, and ideally would like to install in 'debug' mode to try & track down the problem.  Is this possible? Or would it be better to use the command line install (not something I'm familiar with)?  The problem looks very similar to [this](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/39180/what-can-i-do-about-this-error-after-attempting-to-install-civicrm-on-a-wordpres) but that was Wordpress.

Comment: I tried installing on a different site but same hosting company - same result exactly

Comment: I haven't been able to resolve this yet, although I have seen that on another hosting site the problem doesn't happen.  On this site I see this message in Drupal, which might be a clue:   'Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Civi\Core\SettingsBag->combine() (line 354 of /home/acivior1/test.acivi.org.uk/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/SettingsBag.php).

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a hosting problem.  It took a while to resolve, and I don't know what was fixed but it's all OK now. This is one of the problems of using shared hosting, of course - it's cheap but you are vulnerable to arbitrary updates - and there's also the problem of email delivery (I use mailjet to get round this).